# Devexpress gridcrontrol detail gridview does not apply the changes in designer

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

hope you can help me with this issue: I have a GridControl that does not apply the changes made in the designer, when I set that the detail gridview has columns type Memo and is not editable. I configure it by code but the gridview does not take the changes. 
Nor let me change the header of the detail.

```
RepositoryItemMemoEdit riMemoEdit = new RepositoryItemMemoEdit();
gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(riMemoEdit); 
gridView1.Columns["Reglamentaciones"].ColumnEdit = riMemoEdit;
```

Comment: Make sure that the pattern view name matches the relation name in the dataset or the collection property name in case you are using the objects collection as the datasource. See also: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5497

Comment: Thanks Uranus, i just change the name of the relation in the Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For the gridView follow the following:
Click **Run Resigner**
In the **Feature Browser**
select the **Master-Detail**=>**Grid Control Settings**
Set the **ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails** to **true**

Then you can design the details otherwise if the **ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails** is set to false
Dev Express loads the table settings and columns from the Data Source ans skips your design.